# Spring-boot + liquibase: complex data manipulation/migration/population

Tags: java, spring-boot, relational-database, liquibase, data-migration

First off: I'm using spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE with liquibase 3.5.5

If I understand it correctly:

- Liquibase runs before Hibernate is initialized
- Liquibase runs before the spring beans are created
- Liquibase is perfect for db-scheme manipulations

The problem I'm facing is how to do **data-migrations**....

For example: I have 8 tables which are pretty complex connected to each other (multiple foreign keys and cross reference tables). I want to populate those tables through an automated way.

The requirements:

- The population/manipulation must be automated (each environment must be guaranteed to have the same data, directly after start up)
- The population/manipulation must happen in order with the liquibase scripts (when the db-scheme changes later, those scripts should not fail)

So far, I've used 2 approaches:

- `CustomTaskChange` from liquibase, but those classes do not have access to the spring environment, so I ended up writing a lot of manual and complex SQL queries and reusing received ID's etc.
- Manual queries/API calls at the release, but this is very error prone, risky and slow. (we have a cloud service, so until all queries are executed the server is in a inconsistent state)

I don't think I can wire the spring environment in, because the application and spring configuration is not yet completed at that point. At least: it seems Hibernate is not yet loaded as you can see from the logs:

```
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : Reading from public.databasechangelog
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::test: Table test created
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::test: ChangeSet classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::test: ran successfully in 53ms
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] liquibase                                : Successfully released change log lock
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
INFO 50668 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

This is to be expected, since liquibase must update the scheme before the entities can match it.

So... What are the best practices to realize this?

Is there a tool that cooperates with liquibase/spring-boot to manage data-manipulations?

Is it better to just do this manually each release?

**Edit:**

The more I think about it, the more I realize this is plain impossible... 
You would need to setup a spring context for that single script that needs it, and destroy it afterwards. But if your entities do not match the script's version, it will crash... So you would need to revert the codebase to the code when the script was written, or create entities on the fly based on the current DB-scheme...

Comment: you can run liquibase many times you want. You can create hook on some event ([ApplicationPreparedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationPreparedEvent.html) for example) and execute LB from there, or maybe create more sophisticated migration.